# Categorizing using an IF Then Function with non-numerical values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to wring a code to automated categorization of natural and induced fractured by fracture type in a data sheet.  I am trying to use an If Then function for fracture types that are known to be Induced fractures rather than naturally occurring ones.  I have tried two different ways of getting this categorization to work for even a single type by I keep getting compiling errors and syntax errors.  Is there a better way to go about this sort of problem?

```
Sub Simple_if()
    If Range(G4, [G1004]) = "Twist" Then Range(I4, [I1004]) = "Induced"
    End If
```

Also have tried

```
 Dim G As Integer
 For G = 4 To 1004
```

and

```
 Dim I As Integer
 For I = 4 To 1004
    If Cells(G, 5).Value = "Twist" Then Cells(I, 5).Value = "Induced"
```

Comment: Remove the `END IF` line from your first attempt. If you are going to put something after the `Then` on the same line, then an `End If` is not needed. *there also plenty of other issues here, but it's unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You should state the errors you get and on which lines. In your first example you can't compare a whole range with a single value. In your last example you don't define G.

Comment: what columns are you trying to amend? Your top portion amends columns `G & I` but your second attempt is amending column `E`

Answer (score 1):

*If some row on `Column G = "Twist"` then that same row on `Column i` will show `Induced`*

```
Dim i as Long

For i = 4 to 1004
    If Range("G" & i) = "Twist" Then Range("I" & i) = "Induced"
Next i
```

---

If you need to act on the negative result (*I.E. your value does NOT equal `"Twist"`*) you will change to the block version of `If` statement.

```
Dim i as Long

For i = 4 to 1004
    If Range("G" & i) = "Twist" Then 
        Range("I" & i) = "Induced"
    Else
        Range("I" & i) = "Something Else?"
    End If
Next i
```